# How do I get a DropDown to have a selected value when I display the form in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is what I have in the controller:

```
IList<LocationInFacility> locs = LocationsInFacility(custCodeID);
ViewData["LocationsInFacility"] = new SelectList(locs, "ID", "Name", "DL");
```

Here is the view:

```
<label>Location in Facility</label>
<%= Html.DropDownList
        ("LocationsInFacility",(SelectList)ViewData["LocationsInFacility"]) %>
```

Here is the html output, I would have expected "DL" to be selected but it's not:

```
<select id="LocationsInFacility" name="LocationsInFacility">
<option value="">-- Select a Location in Facility --</option>
<option value="DL">DELI</option>
<option value="BK">BAKERY</option>
</select>
```

Why is "DL" not selected?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change the Html.DropDownList to:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("LocationsInFacility") %>
```

Answer (score -2):

Is DL a string in the LocationsInFacility data? You may need to pass the value in if not, rather than the ToString equivalent

Comment: "DL" is the value for Deli.  See the html above.  Are you saying to pass in the word "Deli" instead?

Comment: see this http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/11/11/and-yet-another-asp.net-mvc-bug.aspx